# Deserialization do not work with Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, scheduled-tasks

I have program that deserialize some data from a XML-File. That works very fine, when I start the program with the VS Debugger or click on the .exe file directly. But when i use the Microsoft Task Scheduler to start the program, the deserialization do not work, but the program starts. The task points directly to the directory with the xml file and the .exe.

The Method:

```
    internal static Settings DeserializeSettings()
    {
        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\settings.xml";
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));

        using (FileStream myFileStream =
        new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Settings test = new Settings();
            if (!(myFileStream.Length <= 0))
            {
                 test = (Settings)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
            }
            return test;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's not executing in the right directory. When you create your scheduled task, you need to tell it which directory to start in. Otherwise it will start in the default directory, which is almost certainly not where you want it.

Typically, you put your application settings in the App.Config file for your application. If you use the built-in settings stuff, it's all handled for you. See:

- [How to: Add an Application Configuration File to a C# Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms184658.aspx)
- [Configuring Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kza1yk3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)